# Rigorous geometrical models for InSAR imagery?

Tags: remote-sensing, photogrammetry, radar, insar

I'm looking for rigorous geometrical models for InSAR imagery. I'm familiar with the rigorous models for SAR images, but I don't know the model for InSAR. I searched through the internet, but I didn't find any clear-cut equations concerning this subject.

If anyone knows any books or lecture notes concerning rigorous geometrical models for InSAR imagery, please suggest me.

Comment: please take a look at [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room) and [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2). It may be interesting for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the paper [Application of RPC model for InSAR phase evaluation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6049560&action=search&sortType=&rowsPerPage=&searchField=Search_All&matchBoolean=true&queryText=%28%28%22Abstract%22:rigorous%29%20AND%20InSAR%29)
 is good to start with and then you can continue with the [references of that paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/abstractReferences.jsp?arnumber=6049560&action=search&sortType=&rowsPerPage=&searchField=Search_All&matchBoolean=true&queryText=%28%28%22Abstract%22:rigorous%29%20AND%20InSAR%29)
The paper [Robust Estimating Three-Dimensional Ground Motions from Fusion of InSAR and GPS Measurements](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6024238&action=search&sortType=&rowsPerPage=&searchField=Search_All&matchBoolean=true&queryText=%28%28%22Abstract%22:rigorous%29%20AND%20InSAR%29) is another good resource

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=TJRaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=rigorous%20geometrical%20model%20insar&source=bl&ots=MHrD-3yZIZ&sig=QNcuUxlO1NNhxW4XBNqv7HtMsh0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFQQ6AEwB2oVChMItbGnl5T2xwIVA9saCh2mkgfQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) can be a good resource, too. It's not completely relevant but since rigorous models are extracted from the satellite's orbital motion equation, it can help a lot
Take a look at [lecture notes](http://gps.alaska.edu/jeff/Classes/GEOS655.html). They are not fully related. But I'm telling you that searching key words like "rigorous"+"insar" won't give you much results. You should start with the applications that need these geometric models for example "high accuracy DEM generation insar", "tectonic motion insar", "building extraction insar", etc.

Comment: @Federico Iranian?

Comment: Yes I am; from Isfahan.